# Google Play invalid signature - upload APK

Tags: android, google-play

At first I want to apologize for my english so please be patient :D. To give a bit of context for my problem..

I have published first version of my application in google play. In publishing process I also checked the option that I want to sign the app with Google in the future. Then I discovered that the app has some bugs. So I realize that I want to release new version with fixes.

Now I am trying to upload new APK file (generated with Android Studio) to Google play, but it always said: **"You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (nulllearn more about signingnull). Error from apksigner: null"** .

For the first build I used V1(JAR signature) and V2(Full APK signature). The same signatures I am using now for the new version of application which I am also uploading.

So I am now really confused, that the google wont accept my new generated APK file.

Does anybody know, where should be the problem?

I was trying to solve this problem with my own, but without results, maybe because I am new in mobile development and I didnt have experience with this :/ .

Comment: Can you verify that you are building a 'release' build and not 'debug'?

Comment: Yes, I am using the release build.

Comment: Unsure of the cause, but try removing the build folder and start again. Make sure to check v1 and v2 checkboxes.

Comment: Both checkboxes are checked. Now we realize with my friend(he is also participating in development of this application) that he can build and upload the APK file to google, but me neither.. I have Android studio 3.6.1 and he has 3.5, so I still dont know where is the problem .. :/

Comment: are you using the same keystore  to generate the release apk as your friend? google signed apks still require the uploaded apk to be signed by a specific key

Comment: Sure, I was the first one who build the app and release it to google play :D then I sent key file to my friend. Now his build (apk file) is working in google play console but mine not. I also realized that I can upload App bundle( file with .abb), but APK still not working for me :/ . Can I use bundle(.abb file) to create update when previous application was released with APK file ?

Comment: Of course you can, @William. It doesn't negatively affect your users.